# Java Control of Epson Thermal Receipt Printer

Tags: java, epson

Back in 2007 I wrote some software in Java that controlled an Epson TM90 Receipt Printer.  My software used the JavaPOS API.

It appears that this JavaPOS software no longer exists!

In 2012, what is the correct approach to driving an Epson Receipt printer from Win7 via USB from an application written in Wava?

TIA
BfW

Answer (score 2):

Er [JavaPOS home page](http://www.javapos.com/index.html) seems to be around and activeish?

Comment: Just because it hasn't been updated doesn't mean it no longer exists.